# Java JTextArea, JLabel, and other Components: How to set Location

Tags: java, swing, location, jlabel, jcomponent

If I have a `JLabel`, for example, and I call the `setLocation()` method, nothing happens. Same with all the other `JComponent`s. How can I specify the location? It would be nice to be able to move these `Component`s wherever I want to.

Comment: Unless it is absolutely necessary, don't.  Instead, learn to use the layout managers and don't be afraid to use compound components with different layout managers to get the same effect.  Layout managers take a lot of things into consideration when calculating their layouts, a lot of work you probably don't really want to have to replicate - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer  *"Unless it is absolutely necessary, don't."*  I have yet to see a circumstance that component layout code should not be put in a (possibly custom) layout.  So it is ***never*** absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the `LayoutManager` of your panel or frame is setting the location of the label for you.

What you need to do is set the layout to `null` (this will make it so the frame doesn't try to layout the components by itself):

```
public GUI() 
{
    setLayout(null);
}
```

I don't condone this workaround however, since `LayoutManager`s are extremely useful in mapping out where components should go. Also, when the `LayoutManager` is `null`, you'll have to keep track of new components each time, perform layout computation yourself when the window moves shrink, etc. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for help with `LayoutManager`s

Comment: can I make my own layouts to do the same thing?

Comment: *"I don't condone.."* ..so much as mentioning `null` layouts to newbies.  By the time they could make a `null` layout work robustly, the logic should be encapsulated in a (possibly custom) layout.

Comment: @AndrewThompson  The OP asked a question about a certain problem, I gave him two solutions. One solution explained the problem and how to work around it by setting the `LayoutManager` to `null`; the other was how to work with the problem by using `LayoutManager`s properly (which I recommended), and the OP decides to use the `LayoutManager` in the end. So why the down-vote?

Comment: *"The OP asked a question about a certain problem"*  If the OP asked you how to shoot themselves in the foot, would you give them instructions?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I would point him to a different StackExchange site, or flag it as not a real question. This is a real question however, one that was answered correctly. I don't see the need for you to down-vote me.

Answer (score 2):

The layout manager will position the components for you. It is possible to not use a layout manager and position the components yourself but this is not advised. Please read the following tutorial from oracle http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html